# Running node.js in Windows - how does the command prompt know about the packages

Tags: node.js, command-prompt

I am following:
https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/unit-test-03-basic-testing/
but this question is generally about node rather than testing.  Apologies for the rubbish phrasing as I feel my way here.

I understand that having installed node.js, a new path variable has been added, so now I can type, for example, "npm install --save-dev karma" etc because npm is in the C:\Program Files\nodejs folder now pointed to by the path variable (so the command prompt "knows" what to do with 'npm ...' ).

What I don't understand is how I can type "karma init" at the command line (and it works).  All I can see happened when I "installed" karma is that karma and its dependencies were put in the node_modules subfolder.  There was no system path variable added.  So when in the root folder, how does the command "karma ..." work? How is the command prompt interpreting it?

Answer (score 0):

The command 'karma' works through a command line interface. See karma in node_modules/.bin/karma. This tutorial will help you. http://blog.npmjs.org/post/118810260230/building-a-simple-command-line-tool-with-npm

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I understand that it works through the Windows command line, and having read the link you included I can see that is about create command line commands for npm libraries.  But I am still unclear how I can have the cmd line open in any folder and type "karma ..." and karma runs.  From the article you sent, is it the "symlinking" mentioned in 1.4 that achieves this?  Is there a list I can view of the symlinks on my computer (so can see "karma" listed there)?

Comment: You installed karma-cli globally so the package can run from any folder. https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/